# Every seminorm on a finite dimensional Hausdorff TVS is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity, topological-vector-spaces

Let $E$ be a topological vector space Hausdorff and $p:E \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ any seminorm on $E$. If $E$ is finite dimensional, say $dim(E)=n$, then I want to prove that $p$ is continuous. I thought about proving that the set
$$B:=\{ x \in E \; ; \; p(x)<1\}$$
is a open set. But I don't know how to relate this to the fact that $dim(E)=n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well known that the topology of a finite dimensional Hausdorff vector space is induced by a norm, so we assume $E$ to be a normed space.

Let $N=\{ x\in E\mid p(x)=0\}$, this is a vector sub-space as can be easily verified. Now $p$ descends to $E/N$, where it is a norm and not just a semi-norm, equip $E/N$ with this norm. The projection:
$$\pi: E\to E/N$$
is a linear map between finite dimensional normed spaces. As such it is continuous. Post-compose with $p$ to get that the map:
$$x\mapsto \pi(x)\mapsto p(\pi(x))=p(x)$$
is continuous. As such $p$ is continuous on $E$.

Comment: Great answer! Know how to tell me a reference the result " a finite dimensional Hausdorff vector space is induced by a norm"?

Comment: Follows from the fact that $E$ is isomorphic of $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: For the base field complex numbers yes, but the statement is also true if the base field is the reals. Googling yields [this](http://www.math.uni-konstanz.de/~infusino/Lect8.pdf) as a possible reference. The main idea is that if $e_1,..., e_n$ is a basis of $E$ the the map $\Bbb C^n \to E$, $(x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto x_1 e_1 +... + x_n e_n$ is an isomorphism (bijectivity, and continuity are obvious, the only thing to check continuity of the inverse).

Comment: Why the compose is continuous?

Comment: $\pi$ is continuous and $p_{E/N}: E/N\to\Bbb R$ is continuous. So $p=p_{E/N}\circ\pi$ is  continuous.

Comment: But, why $p=p_{E/N} \circ \pi$? It's because $p_{E/N}$ is the form $$p_{E/N}(x)=\inf_{\pi(x)} \; p(x)?$$

Comment: This is the way it works. If you divide out the null space of a semi-norm you have that if $\pi(x)=\pi(y)$ then $p(x)=p(y)$. The proof is trivial: $x-y\in N$ so $p(x)= p(y+(x-y)) ≤ p(y)+(x-y)=p(y) = p(x+(y-x)) ≤ p(x) + p(y-x)=p(y)$.

Comment: But for me this is still not clear why $p(x)=(p_{E/N}\circ \pi)(x)$ for all $x \in E$.

Comment: $p_{E/N}$ is defined in that way, the above calculation shows that this is well defined. If you want to use another definition you have to do a similar calculation to see that this remains true.